# What means "breaking ties" in context of sorting

Tags: terminology, requirements, sorting

As an interview assignment for software developer, I have received the task. I have a list of children, and the task is: sort children ascending by their `birth_date` timestamp, **breaking ties by ID**

The structure of child is:

```json
"child": {
  "id": "14"
  "name": "John"
  "birth_date": "1990-12-20T11:50:48Z"
}
```

I can not get the meaning of phrase "breaking ties" in the given context. I guess it can be one of following:

- if `birth_date` is the same - first goes child with lower `id`
- while sorting using `birth_date`, ignore `-` sign.

Comment: It's probably the first option that you gave.

Comment: this is an english language question

Comment: As others have noted, it's almost certainly the first interpretation. I just want to give a piece of advice, though: if the interview is conducted in person, or if there's an easy way to contact them, feel free to *ask for clarification* right there and then. Nobody with any sense will hold that against you.

Answer (score 5):

In the context of sorting, tie breaking is about ensuring a total order.

Take a look at the example data:

```
  "id": "14" //made up data
  "name": "John" //real data
  "birth_date": "1990-12-20T11:50:48Z" //real data
```

There are exactly two pieces of real data, what happens if there are two people with identical names and birth dates?

The sorting algorithm can't decide which one goes first, or even if they are essentially the same thing, and it should just discard on copy.

This is a real problem because sorting two separate copies of a list could result in two different orderings, comparing them by element pairs (`a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && ...`) would then result in false.

This is why a total order is important.

Now there is no more real data to make the distinction on, so how are we going to ensure that the elements will always be sorted into the same order. The answer is to break the tie by using the made up data. Its completely arbitrary but now no mater how often the list is scrambled and resorted, it will always sort the elements into the same positions allowing comparison by comparing each element pair.

Answer (score 4):

A [tie-break](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tie-breaker) is an extra play when two players have the same number of points, to decide who is the winner.

I never heard this expression in sorting, but transposing from [tennis](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tie-break) into that area, it means that every thing else being equal,  you make an extra comparison on id to decide who's first.

Would you speak of a linked list I would hesitate more, because a [tie](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tie) is also a link or a connection. But even with this meaning, in your context of sorting, the only connection that could make sense would be that of equality.

Comment: The concept of "ties" in sorting is certainly common enough to have a keyword for it in SQL. To "break a tie" is not a technical term, but simply means dealing with ties by taking some additional step to ensure unique rankings - often a step that is spurious or random in nature (such as tossing a coin to determine a football match, or ranking data by Id).

Comment: @Steve Thanks for this enlightening confirmation. Indeed SQL [TOP WITH TIES](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-ties-clause/) refers to equal values. On the other side C++ sees ties very differently,  [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) being a group of elements linked together into a tuple. It's also used in sorting, but just to create a lexicographic order between the elements.

Answer (score 1):

When you sort data, it is a useful property that the same keys will always be sorted in the exact same order. That will happen obviously if no two different keys can compare equal, but if two keys are equal they could be sorted in either order. Not being able to decide who wins is called a “tie” in sports.

To avoid the situation you add some extra data that is unique, and that may be completely irrelevant to the sorting, but it decides which item comes first, always in the same way. That’s the “tie break”, very common in tennis.

The information must be unique and stable, and ids should be always unique and stable.